# Changing from THREE.Geometry to THREE.BufferGeometry with THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

Hi I'm new to Three JS and need a little help. I am using a piece of code I found to create a sphere of random points but since THREE.Geometry has since been depreciated I need to change THREE.Geometry to THREE.BufferGeometry in the code.

The original code is :

```
var pointsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {


    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
     
    // for simplicity I have omitted script 
    // that would be placed here for creating random 
    // values for vector.x, vector.y, vector.z etc etc

    pointsGeometry.vertices.push(vector);

}
```

So now I believe I need to use:

```
const pointsGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
```

but how do I push each vector into an array that exists in an attribute of pointsGeometry named 'vertices'?

In the for loop I cannot use :

```
pointsGeometry.setAttribute( 'vertices', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vector ) );
```

I thought I needed to manually create an array 'vectorsArray' and push each vector into the array in the for loop and then add it after the loop

```
pointsGeometry.setAttribute( 'vertices', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vectorsArray ) );
```

while this does create a vertices attribute and add an array of 1000, each value is NaN when it should be:

```
0: Object { x: -21.16441539757467, y: 112.77250047881454, z: -37.63426937227097, … } etc
```

I have checked that vectorsArray does posses the correct values which they do, but for some reason they are not getting passed into pointsGeometry.setAttribute( 'vertices'). What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

const points = [];
const point = new THREE.Vector3();

for ( let i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {

    point.random();
    points.push( point.x, point.y, point.z );

}

geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( points, 3 ) );
```

When using this geometry with `THREE.Points`, it will create a random point cloud.

Comment: Thanks but I think I need to rethink it entirely as that just creates 3000 values like 0: 40.622398376464844, 1: -79.433837890625, 2: 81.21952056884766, 3: etc, 4: etc, 5: etc when it needs to create 1000 entries of 3 values like: 1: Object { x: 91.8137727932649, y: 10.509176330315706, z: 78.69060100961515, … }, 2: Object { x: -43.05669641279263, y: 39.615109575280584, z: 107.45459939364815, … }, 3: Object { x: -42.4875035598819, y: 50.75474777485035, z: 99.4013919602344, … } etc

Comment: @cannon303 In the end, you will work with a flat array of numbers, not of Vector3, for vertices.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will need to change much more script then. Seems a shame that they would change it to something more abstract.

Comment: The above code will perform so much better than the previous approach with `THREE.Geometry`.